# INStartVideoCallIntent from call history and CallKit video button

Tags: ios, callkit

INStartVideoCallIntent is sent from CallKit video button tap and when we tap on call history’s record.
Is there any way to know is intent is sent from CallKit or history screen?

Answer (score 0):

I hope from the intent we can't differentiate. 
But we can write some logic from our app to differentiate both the logics.

1. If the intent is sent from history screen, our app is going to intiate the call from the intent. So there will not be any active call for that number/id.
2. If the intent is sent from video button, there is the active call
   and going to start as the video call.

So, based on the active calls we can differentiate.

Comment: Yeah thats one way to do it, but it would be nice to have somehow to know it without it. Thnaks